# Token must begin at start of line

Tags: token, lex

So I got these tokens in my lex file:

```
\$\$.*          ; /* comment */
\$(.|\n)*\$     ; /* comment */
">="            return GE; 
"<="            return LE; 
":="            return AT;
"~="            return NEQ;
"if"            return IF; 
"else"          return ELSE;
"then"          return THEN;
"elif"          return ELIF;
"fi"            return FI;
"for"           return FOR;
"until"         return UNTIL;
"step"          return STEP;
"do"            return DO;
"done"          return DONE;
"repeat"        return REP;
"stop"          return STOP;
"return"        return RET;
"program"       return PROG;
"module"        return MOD;
"start"         return ST;
"end"           return END;
"void"          return VD;
"const"         return CT;
"number"        return NB;
"array"         return ARR;
"string"        return SG;
"function"      return FC;
"public"        return PB;
"forward"       return FW;
```

And I wanted to know if there is a way to make a token match only if it starts at the beginning of a line.
For example if in my program I write it like this:

```
start
```

It should work but if I do:

```
    start
```

or

```
program start
```

it should not work

Comment: is it start of line or start of file? for start of line wouldnt the `^` regex option do it?

Comment: documentation for lex: http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `^` at the beginning of a (f)lex pattern, which will cause the pattern to only match if it is either at the beginning of the input or immediately follows a newline character.

See [the Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html) for a complete list of regular expression syntaxes which are accepted. (It's not a very long document.)